# Java interface function with extra parameter

Tags: java, design-patterns, interface

I am beginner in Java and OOP. I have one interface, for example animal, that can shout.

```
public interface Animal{
    public void shout();
}
```

My class `Dog` implement the interface, and can shout at anybody.

```
public class Dog implements Animal{
    public void shout(){
        System.out.println("Woof woof");
    }
}
```

I want a specific dog, class `SmarterDog`, that can shout to someone specific.

So my function would be `void shout(String somebody)`, so we have just one extra parameter, but still approximatively the same code. It's still an `Animal`, so it should implement `Animal`.

How can I organize my code to simulate this function?
What should I do for more complex functions? Should I create an extra function in the class that implements my interface?

Comment: "_Should I create an extra function in the class that implements my interface?_" **Yes.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method `shout()` in the interface and the method `shout(String somebody)` in the `SmarterDog` class have the same name but they are different methods. In Java, a method is not only identified by its name but also by its argument types.

They might have some overlap in their implementation but that is not relevant. Interfaces are not about implementation. (Java 8 does allow you to define default method implementations in interfaces, but that is mostly a convenience feature added to the language.)

What you could do is put the common code into a helper method in some other class and call it from both `shout` methods. You could also define a class responsible for shouting and add an instance of it to your animal objects. This is basically an implementation of the strategy pattern - sounds complicated but if your class hierarchy gets more complex, it might be worthwhile. The main advantage is that the "shouting" aspect of the `Animal` is separated from the other aspects.

I would probably also change the name of the method with argument to `shoutTo(String somebody)` to make it clearer.

Answer (score 0):

Java 8 introduced [default methods](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/defaultmethods.html), which allows you to specify a default implementation in your interface which implementing classes don't need to define if they don't want to.

Your example doesn't quite work for this, since it's not clear how `shout(String)` and `shout()` relate (i.e. it doesn't seem like one would call the other), but a slightly different API would work:

```
public interface Animal {
  /** Shout, including a message. */
  void shout(String message);

  /** Shout without a custom message. */
  default void shout() {
    shout("");
  }
}
```

Since `shout()` is defined in the interface all implementations get it for free, and they only need to implement `shout(String)`, which might look something like this:

```
public void shout(String message) {
  String call = "Woof woof";
  if (!message.isEmpty()) {
    call += ", " + message;
  }
  System.out.println(call);
}
```

Default methods have some limitations (they must be public, they have no access to the object's fields, etc.) but can be very useful for avoiding redundant method implementations in subclasses.

Comment: But doesn't this mean that *all* classes that implement the interface need to implement `shout(String)`.

Comment: Well yes; that's the point of an interface. Like I said the API OP is describing isn't compatible with `default` methods, but a similar one (such as my example) could be.

Comment: As I understood the original question, *all* classes implementing the interface should have `shout()` but only some of them should have `shout(String)`. Therefore I wouldn't call your implementation similar to the original requirement.

Comment: And I'm suggesting an alternative way to structure your code that is easy, standard, and modern, in the hope that it helps OP design a better interface.

Comment: Still don't get it. Why do you suggest declaring a method in an interface that only makes sense for specific implementations of that interface? Isn't that against all design rules? (Your point about default implementations may be helpful for the OP, but it does not address his main question.)

Answer (score 0):

> I want a specific dog, class SmarterDog, that can shout to someone specific.

Create a new class which extends Dog.

> How can I organize my code to simulate this function?

Add the method you need to the newly created class.

> It's still an Animal, so it should implement Animal.

SpecificDog is still Animal.

```
public class SpecificDog extends Dog {
    public void shout(String somebody) {
        System.out.println("Woof at " + somebody);
    }
}
```

> What should I do for more complex functions? Should I create an extra function in the class that implements my interface?

As I understand you'll need to add specific behaviours to specific classes which would extend Dog and/or implement Animal. So, just create your classes with necessary behaviours (methods). Don't overcomplicate your model from very beginning. Try to keep your abstractions as simple as possible. If you spot a contract which can be moved up (to  class/interface) then do it.

```
// somewhere in your code
SpecificDog dog = new SpecificDog();
dog.shout();
dog.shout("stranger");
```

Output

```
Woof woof
Woof at stranger
```